# How to abort / cancel the loading operation of a store in Sencha ExtJS v6?

Tags: extjs, store, abort, operation, cancellation

I have used these two sources below:

- [Abort an ext js grid store ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590865/abort-an-ext-js-grid-store-ajax-call)
- [Selectively aborting an ajax request sent via Extjs Direct proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251440/selectively-aborting-an-ajax-request-sent-via-extjs-direct-proxy)

but none of them is valid in the version 6 of extjs

How could I cancel the load operation every time a new operation starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 6.0.2 of ExtJS some things have changed and the `Operation` class has and `abort` method

There is no getOperation method but there is the `beforeload` which is useful to grab the operation.

By collecting one or more operations you can safely `abort` them before starting a new operation.

The following Typescript class will be of help:

```
module ext_ts {
interface Abortable {
    abort(): void
}

export class AutoAbortPreviousOperation {
    private _storeOperations: Array<Abortable> = []

    applyOnStore(store): any {
        let me = this

        return store.on({
            destroyable: true,
            beforeload: function (theStore, operation, eOpts) {
                let lastOperation = me._storeOperations.pop()

                if (lastOperation) {
                    console.log("aborting previous operation safely")

                    lastOperation.abort()   //this abort is safe so no need to check !lastOperation.isComplete()
                } else {
                    //nop
                }

                me._storeOperations.push(operation)    //add this operation for later usage

                return true //let the loading begin
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

Note that the `statusCode` of a request which is forcely cancelled by the user is: **-1**

Useful links:

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.operation.Operation.html
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.Store.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the underlying proxy in the store is a AJAX based proxy. In that case a simple

```
store.getProxy().abort();
```

should do the job.